# Get Encoding type of NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsstring, nsdata

I have some chunks of data that are encoded with random techniques, say first chunk is encoded by `NSUTF8StringEncoding` another one with `NSASCIIStringEncoding` or `kCFStringEncodingWindowsArabic`.

I don't know which chunk is encoded with which type of encoding. I have tried multiple options e.g. if result is nil then decode with `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`, but to no avail. Is there any way to determine a specific chunk of data is encoded with type of Encoding ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That encoding mechanism is broken then.  There is no perfect solution to your issue.

Comment: If you are retrieving data with a WebService, the response headers may give you an hint on the encoding in the "Charset" value.

Comment: @Larme Good suggestion but I am not retrieving data from WebService.

Comment: I'm afraid that you may then have to test all the encodings, and find a way to qualify one as the correct one.

Comment: That is Humongous task :(

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer for your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9836989/2923506

> This is a copy&paste code adapted to ARC of the user MiiChiel, because it's a good answer. "if ASCII and UTF8 give both a string in return. For instance: UTF8 gives me some extra characters (negative result) and ASCII are showing the right characters (positive result)."

```
NSString *responseString, *responseStringASCII, *responseStringUTF8;

responseStringASCII = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
if (!responseStringASCII)
{
   // ASCII is not working, will try utf-8!

    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
else
{
    //  ASCII is working, but check if UTF8 gives less characters

    responseStringUTF8  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if(responseStringUTF8 != nil && [responseStringUTF8 length] < [responseStringASCII length])
    {
        responseString  =   [responseStringUTF8 retain];
    }
    else 
    {
        responseString  =   [responseStringASCII retain];
    }

}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I already checked that, there are number of Encodings out there what do you think is it feasible solution ?

Comment: Got it. I would say there is a heuristic answer for your question but I don't think there is a unflawed solution.

Comment: Let's hope I get what I want or I will have to write a very lengthy script :(

Comment: So if you You can create a category to your object and save the encodetype to it.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C includes a built-in way to detect a the encoding of a string embedded in NSData.

(Note, if your case you still need to partition each chunk into a separate NSData objects.)

```
NSData* data = // Assign your NSData object...

NSString* string;
NSStringEncoding encoding = [NSString stringEncodingForData:data encodingOptions:nil convertedString:&string usedLossyConversion:nil];
```